# Why I can not view an apex class on the developer console?

Tags: apex, trigger, developer-console

In my org has one class named **CreateZendeskTicketsFromQuotes** it's used on a trigger, But I can not view the class on **developer console** and **Apex Classes**. I am an admin, need help to view the class.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you cannot view this class because it is part of a managed package installed in your org.

Apex that's part of a managed package has IP protection applied, which hides the code from your org - it's proprietary to the vendor of the managed package. If you open a managed Apex class in your org through the Developer Console, you'll just see a blank.

There's no way to change this behavior. If you need help with the specific code-level behavior of a managed Apex class, contact the managed package vendor for assistance.

Comment: the trigger was created by one developer. he used the apex class, how to confirm that, this class is a part of the managed code. I assume that he may put some filters so that I can not view the class.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "filter" on an Apex class. It would be helpful if you would [edit] your question to provide more details of the behavior you see, including screen shots.